# Passing a multidimensional PHP array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an array($my_array) that looks something like:

```
array(2) {
[25]=>int(10)
[30]=>int(8)
}
```

I'd like to assign it to a javascript array, but am having difficulties doing it.  Any suggestions?

Edit: At first, I thought I could just assign it like a string, but that isn't working:

```
var photo_limit = $my_array;
```

I tried also doing a var_dump into my js value.

I'm currently trying to use something like:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($my_array); $i++){
echo "a[$i]='".$a[$i]."';\n";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: how are you doing it now? when do you need to initiate it?

Comment: I would use json_encode to encode the object as JSON. JSON is perfect when working with JS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is to use `json_encode`. See [json_encode reference](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Used like this:

```
<script>
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array)?>;
</script>
```

Note, hovewer, that you'll receive Javascript object, instead of array. At a glance the only difference is if you have string keys in your array, you'll be able to access them in JS like `array.*string key*`, i.e. using dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

1: `json_encode` your PHP array.

2: Decode the JSON string in JavaScript using `eval`(alternative: [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/))

```
<script>
    var arr = eval('(<?php echo json_encode($thePhpArray); ?>)');
</script>
```