# Assign two dimensional php to two dimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a two dimensional javascript array that I want to assign to a php array.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
var js_array= [[]];
js_array = <?php echo $result;?>;
```

I have basically created a two dimensional php array and assigned to a two dimensional javascript array.

I don't seem to see any logical issue in this code. Can someone please point out as to why this approach might not work?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in `$result`? If it itself is the array, the code will be `js_array = Array;`; if it's a string, how did you build it?

Comment: @newfurniturey,$result is a two dimensional php array. So, I want to assign it to a javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `echo` an array, only a string. Look at the `json_encode` function in PHP: https://www.php.net/json_encode you'll find this does what you want.

```
var js_thing = <?php echo json_encode($result);?>;
```

Comment: json is great for this, you can do `var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($a_lot_of_things); ?>;` and it will work - strings, numbers, arrays, including mixed ones, and more, always properly encoded as data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var js_array= []; 
js_array = <?php echo json_encode($result);?>;
```

Try `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `json_encode` is a good option. However, the object you receive in JS is not exactly an array. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040749/passing-a-multidimensional-php-array-to-javascript) shows you pretty simple how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php 
    $arr = array(
            array(1,2,3,4,7),
            array(5,3,6,8),
            array(0,12,34,54,65)
        );
    $arr_str = '[';
    foreach ($arr as $mv) {
        $arr_str .= '[';
        foreach ($mv as $sv) {
            $arr_str .= $sv.',';
        }
        $l = strlen($arr_str);
        if(substr($arr_str, -1) == ','){
            $arr_str = substr($arr_str, 0, $l-1);
        }
        $arr_str .= '],';
    }
    $l = strlen($arr_str);
    if(substr($arr_str, -1) == ','){
        $arr_str = substr($arr_str, 0, $l-1);
    }
    $arr_str .= '];';       
?>
var js_a =<?php echo $arr_str; ?>
```

Its the hard way.. and probably sucks.. ;)